# Excel-VBA - Search and match a value and copy all rows to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsArr()
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SP1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SP2")

With ws1
    wsArr = .Range(.Cells(6, 3), .Cells(LastRow(ws1), 8)).Value 'I use 8 here, because the last column from my table that I want to copy has the index 8 (letter H). I think my array setting is incorret: Range(.Cells(6, 3)
End With

Dim findStr As String
findStr = InputBox("Order ID")

Dim i As Long, r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ws2
    .Range("A17:C17").Value = Array("Product", "Qtt", "Price")
    For i = LBound(wsArr) To UBound(wsArr)
        If wsArr(i, 1) = findStr Then
            r = LastRow(ws2) + 1
            .Cells(r, 1) = wsArr(i, 1) 
            .Cells(r, 2) = wsArr(i, 2)
            .Cells(r, 3) = wsArr(i, 3)
        End If
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

On my spreadsheet (SP1) I have the current table with range starting on C6:

```
Row#/Column    C      D           E          F       G
    5:         ID   Client      Product     Qtt    Price
    6:         1     Emma      Gold Rings    2      5
    7:         2     Becka    Bronze Rings   1      20
    8:         3     Wanda      Earings      1      30
    9:         3     Wanda      Necklace     1      40
```

I want to copy from SP1 to my second spreadsheet (SP2), when order ID finds a match. For example, I input order ID = 6 and the result on SP2 with the starting range from A18:C18, should be something like this:

```
   Row#/Column          A          B       C
    17:                Product     Qtt    Price
    18:                Earings      1      30
    19:                Necklace     1      40
```

But for some reason, my wsArr is empty when going inside the "For" cycle. Am I putting the range in cells wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `LastRow(ws1)`?

Comment: I edited the post with the function LastRow() that was missing. The value of LastRow(ws1) = 15 and LastRow(ws2) = 40

Comment: You aren't passing 8 to LastRow, and it should be 7 not 8 any way.

Comment: Are you sure `wsArr` is empty? Those errors notwithstanding I don't see why it should be empty.

Comment: It's not totally empty - it's populated with data from C1:H6.